# Angular (Javascript) how to control the speed of mousemove event?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, mousemove

I am trying to draw on a canvas using mouse move event

You can see the working demo on this [blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ti33lh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)
I am calling this function on mouse move to draw a rectangle

```
 updateDraw(e: MouseEvent) {

    this.previousCoordinates = this.currentCoordinates;
    this.currentCoordinates = HelloComponent.getCoordinatesOnCanvas(this.canvas.nativeElement, e);
    if (this.drawingMode) {
      HelloComponent.createShape(this.shapes, this.ctx, this.startCoordinates,
        this.currentCoordinates, this.previousCoordinates, true);
      this.endCoordinates = this.currentCoordinates;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that if I move the mouse too fast I get multiple rectangles, ( i am assuming that the clear rectangle doesn't work since mouse move is too fast) how can I avoid this there should be only 1 rectangle in 1 drag draw?

[image]

**Edit:** I want to be able to draw more than 1 rectangle, here I am tracking and clearing previous co ordinates

```
  private static createShape(shape: Shapes, context: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
    start: Coordinates, end: Coordinates, prev: Coordinates,
    dotted: boolean) {

    context.clearRect(start.x, start.y, (prev.x - start.x), (prev.y - start.y));
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the speed of movement. You're most likely not tracking the current previous value.

Comment: @Reactgular I edited I am tracking and clearing the rectangle in the function

Comment: `this.previousCoordinates = this.currentCoordinates` is this done at the right time? Should be done after the rect is cleared.

Comment: @Reactgular still the same thing happens (created a new blitzy) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epezro?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: simply change the `clearRect()` call to `context.clearRect(0,0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcwhzr)

Explanation:

You have the right idea, the problem is that the area you're sending to `clearRect` doesn't actually include the border. Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/strokeRect) (emphasis mine),

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.strokeRect() method of the Canvas 2D API
>   draws a rectangle that is stroked (**outlined**) according to the current
>   strokeStyle and other context settings.

So, to clear the border you actually need to account for the border width when you attempt to clear it.

```
const borderWidth = 1;
const x = Math.min(start.x, prev.x) - borderWidth;
const y = Math.min(start.y, prev.y) - borderWidth;
const width = Math.abs(start.x - prev.x) + (2 * borderWidth);
const height = Math.abs(start.y - prev.y) + (2 * borderWidth);

context.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: or simply change the `clearRect()` call to  `context.clearRect(0,0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
`

Comment: @Randy Casburn Thats a good point but I want to be able to draw more than 1 rectangles at a tim

Comment: @Vlad274 Excellent, Thanks!

Comment: @dota2pro - What you will discover (most likely) is that you will run into artifacts like this being produced the more you draw onto the canvas. It is a best practice to use two canvas elements. One that is the active drawing canvas and the second in is the permanent display canvas. The drawing canvas gets the treatment you provide here, but the finished drawing is then painted into the permanent canvas element. Lots of resources to discover about this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn just understood what you meant, I think that will make my life very easy if I have 2 canvases

Comment: Yes, very much so. Also, I guess I could have mentioned they "drawing" canvas is transparent and overlays the "permanent" one. I bet you figured that out already.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes